# How can I upgrade newtonsoft in outsystems 10

Tags: json.net, outsystems

I'm trying to upgrade outsystems eSpaces from version 9 to 10 and I'm facing this error:

Internal Error

Compilation Error.
bin\OutSystems.RESTService.Runtime.dll: error CS1705: Assembly 'OutSystems.RESTService.Runtime, Version=10.0.1115.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)

Could anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may be facing the same error, I solved publishing system components.